# Get the fields (fieldLayout) of the section. Not the entry

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel, eager-loading

Can I get all the fields of a section? For example, I have channel events, I want the fields in that section, but not related to any specific event.

I want to know all the fields (not the values), before actually executing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the fields from a section since sections have no field layout. Sections have several entry types and those are responsible for the fields.

```
$entryType->getFieldLayout()->getFields();
```

You can get all types in a section with

```
$section->getEntryTypes();
```

Comment: But a section with a handler has a fieldLayout, right? Like the layout of the section 'news'. Which is different of the section 'event'

Comment: Nope, the field layout is attached to the entry type that is connected to the section, never to the section itself